# Re-Loading of objects in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object

I have a model Sample with has_many association car.

```
x = Sample.new
x.car
```

It loads the association from the database.

But then whenever I do x.car, it doesnt make a call to database. I would like to call the database after the first call.

What I am doing now is to restart the interpretor!!

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3):

Just do:

```
x.car.reload
```

The association will be reloaded from your db.

Answer (score 0):

The association object is reloaded when the association is invoked with a parameter resolving to `true`.

```
a.car(true)
```